# Cern ROOT 5.34 error message using functions

Tags: c++, function, root-framework

I'm using the Cern ROOT version 5.34 and I have a problem using functions. The same message error always appear.

For example (using a very simple function):

```
 *******************************************
  *                                         *
  *        W E L C O M E  to  R O O T       *
  *                                         *
  *   Version   5.34/36      5 April 2016   *
  *                                         *
  *  You are welcome to visit our Web site  *
  *          http://root.cern.ch            *
  *                                         *
  *******************************************

ROOT 5.34/36 (v5-34-36@v5-34-36, Apr 05 2016, 10:25:45 on win32)

CINT/ROOT C/C++ Interpreter version 5.18.00, July 2, 2010
Type ? for help. Commands must be C++ statements.
Enclose multiple statements between { }.
root [0] #include <iostream>
Note: File "iostream" already loaded
root [1] using namespace std;
root [2] void hello(){cout << "Hi!" << endl;}
Limitation: Function can not be defined in a command line or a tempfile
You need to write it in a source file (tmpfile)(1)
*** Interpreter error recovered ***
root [3]
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: This may be a hint: `Limitation: Function can not be defined in a command line or a tempfile
You need to write it in a source file (tmpfile)(1)`

Answer (score 0):

If you used root 6, which supports all C++11 features, you could define a [lambda](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) function instead, like so

```
auto hello = [](){ cout << "Hi!" << endl; };
```

You can then call it just like a regular function

```
hello();
```